# Create subfolders inside firebase storage from flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I would like to know if it is possible to create subfolders in firebase from flutter.

My goal is to have a  student profile with the classes currently being taken,,, with the option of uploading his or her notes to firebase, for each course, so other students can see them when they visit his or her profile.

I create a folder in firebase storage console, and after that my plan is to have a users subfolder, and inside the subfolder, a subfolder for each user, then a set of subfolders for each course of each user, and inside a subfolder of a course, the note files that can be downloaded by others.

So like this Folder/users/myprofile/myclasses/math3/files.format

Is it possible with firebase and flutter? Or would i have to create them manually? Thank you

Comment: Firebase Storage (based on Google Cloud Storage) doesn't really have folders at all.  Each bucket is just a set of objects with paths that can look like they are organized with folders. If you want to create something that looks like a "folder", then just write the file with the full path directly, and don't worry about the intermediate step of creating a folder like you would with a computer's filesystem. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders